# Can't figure out why I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerExceptio

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I looked at a couple other treads and I still couldn't find out where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to make an array of Account objects and scan from a text file to fill it out. Thanks for any help or direction pointing.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Bank {

    private static Account[] accounts = new Account[10];
    private static int numAccounts = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  { 
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("bankdata.txt"));

        for(int i=0; i<accounts.length;i++){
            accounts[i] = new Account(null, i, i); //(client, balance, accountNum)
        }

        while(fileScan.hasNext()){
            accounts[numAccounts].getClient().setFName(fileScan.next());
            accounts[numAccounts].getClient().setLName(fileScan.next());
            accounts[numAccounts].getClient().setAge(fileScan.nextInt());
            accounts[numAccounts].getClient().setPhoneNum(fileScan.nextInt());
            accounts[numAccounts].setBalance(fileScan.nextDouble());
            accounts[numAccounts].setAccountNum(fileScan.nextInt());

            numAccounts++;
            System.out.println(accounts[numAccounts]);
        }
        fileScan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've looked at pretty much **any** previous thread on this subject, then you'd know what the most important bit of information is, information that your question lacks. Come on now, what line number throws the NPE??

Comment: Can you please share your stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry went looked away while I tried somethings it was line 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how you initialize your Account objects, all your Clients are null:

```
accounts[i] = new Account(null, i, i); //(client, balance, accountNum)
```

Then when you try to use a Client variables,

```
accounts[numAccounts].getClient().setFName(fileScan.next());
```

you'll get the NPE thrown.

Solution: don't use null clients. Create your Client in the while loop:

```
while(fileScan.hasNext()){
    String fName = fileScan.next();
    String lName = fileScan.next();
    int age = fileScan.nextInt();
    String phoneNumber = fileScan.next();

    Client client = new Client(....); //use info above

    accounts[numAccounts].setClient(client);
    accounts[numAccounts].setBalance(fileScan.nextDouble());
    accounts[numAccounts].setAccountNum(fileScan.nextInt());

    numAccounts++;
    System.out.println(accounts[numAccounts]);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense the problem I'm having when I try not to make it null is that client is made of 2 strings and 2 ints so when I try to give client a value I get told that constructor is undefined. Edit: I just looked at the code you gave me I'm going to try it out thank you.

Comment: @Espinal: then use a constructor that makes sense. Only you have all the code, so you'll need to figure it out. Note that a phone number should **never** be an int. It should be a String.

Comment: Alrighty I took care of that int. I'll keep at it with what I got from you two thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You your self setting client as **null**  , and then calling function on null reference that is why you are getting `NPE`

```
accounts[i] = new Account(null, i, i); //(client, balance, accountNum)
```

Calling a method on a null reference or trying to access a field of a null reference will trigger a NPE.

**Example :**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object obj = null;
        obj.toString(); //cause Null Pointer Exception
    }
}
```